# Jasper reports content on last page, other pages show empty space

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to present a content only on the last page of the report and I know how to do this but what I did is place this content in the footer. What happens is that I get an empty space where the content  appears on the last page. 
I am not familiar with Jasper reports too much so I am looking for a solution where the content for the last page will not leave an empty space between the report table and the footer. 
The content doesn't need to be in footer necessarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this :-

```
1:- There is a band called "Last Page Footer" in report which you can use 
    to print the content only on the last page. To add "Last Page Footer" 
    band go to "Report Inspector" and right click on the band and add.

2:- You can also achieve this by adding Report Groups option, to add report 
    groups go to report inspector and right click on the report and click on the
    "Add Report Group" and add both Header and Footer, Header can be used as
    summary band for graphs and footer can be used as last page footer.
```

Comment: Using the Last Page Footer. Thank you